# viewport autoMaximize causes Timeout waiting for window.innerHeight to change on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, touch, extjs

I have a problem with my app in that we are trying to get as much real estate on the screen as possible and therefore trying to hide the address bar when it is not in use.

I can achieve this by setting the autoMaximize value to true. My problem is when I navigate to this page I get an error Timeout waiting for window.innerHeight to change.

When this error is show I have a white page on my phone but if I then press the refresh button it will actually load the page.

I have attempted to use a fullscreen panel as most docs explain but this will not hide the address bar.

This is completely cut down but I am even getting the error with the following code:

```
Ext.Application({


launch:function(){

    Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype:'panel',
        fullscreen:true,
        html:'dfghdfgsd'
    });

},
viewport:{
    autoMaximize: true
}
});
```

I'm not exactly sure how to explain this issue best because I have tried so many different ways to sort it out. Just hoping someone has came across something similar?

Comment: Did the answer below fix your problem. If yes, then accept it, otherwise tell us what did not work and what error you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running PhoneGap + Touch on iOS, `autoMaximize` should always be set to FALSE per a Sencha employee comment on [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?164247-quot-Timeout-waiting-for-window.innerHeight-to-quot-error-when-running-the-application-on-iOS) thread (links to the Sencha forum).

I'm still seeing this issue with Touch 2.3.0 (Oct 2013), so I've added logic like this:

```
   Ext.application({
     name: 'MyApp',
     viewport: {
       autoMaximize: (typeof(Ext.browser.is.PhoneGap) === 'undefined' || !Ext.browser.is.PhoneGap)
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

When I'm working in debug mode (with an uncompiled version of my app), I also get this error when `autoMaximize` is set to `true`. To solve this problem I simply comment out the **line 64** in **sdk/src/viewport/Ios.js** which is :

```
Ext.Logger.error("Timeout waiting for window.innerHeight to change", this);
```

Hope this helps